# MSSQL - DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this form

```
class FromToForm(Form):
   ModelChoiceField(queryset=TblWorkPlace.objects.all().distinct('work_place_name'))
```

Django writes this error message:

```
DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

Is there some workaround?

Comment: If you're trying to get unique values, why don't you use ChoiceField instead of ModelChoiceField?  The whole point of ModelChoiceField is that it allows you to select whole rows by pk, which is at odds with grouping by work_place_name

Answer (score 0):

**distinct('field_name')** is not supported in MySQL. It only support **distinct()**

MySQL is fine when you want to test out, but most (if not all) database in production do not use Mysql but Postgres.

The good thing with using Postgres is that you unlock a lot of special feature that Django have specifcly for Postgres.

Comment: MySQL != MSSQL.